# Survivability Analysis whereby study drop put/ censoring indicates a positive result

Tags: censoring, kaplan-meier, sensitivity-analysis

I am trying to conduct a survivability analysis (particularly a Kaplain-Meier curve) on data for estimating the likelihood of university drop-outs over time. The study began in 2015 (accounting for people joining Uni from 2015 onwards) and finished in 2020. So this study uses right censoring. Certain university courses are longer than others. My analysis is in R

For demonstration a simplified version of my data is given below. The 'reason for leaving' variable is coded whereby 0 = still at university, 1 = drop-out, and 3 = graduated.

| pupil id | Year Entered Uni | Year Left Uni | Complete Time taken at Uni (years) | Reason for leaving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2017 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2018 | 2019 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015 | 2018 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 2019 | *NA* | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | 2016 | 2017 | 1 | 1 |

From my understanding, in a generic survivability analysis model cases 1 and 3 would be treated the same as case 4, given that they were all censored from the study (they would be removed from the pool of eligible data points from the year they left the data). However, cases 1 and 3 successfully graduated from university so they represent 0% odds of dropping out, whereas case 4 still has a possibility of dropping out.

Therefore:

- Should I be accounting for this in my analysis?
- If so, I was thinking of just setting graduates to remain infinitely at Uni after they graduate, to substitute the fact they never dropped out. Would this be appropriate?
- If the previous solution is not appropriate, is there another way I could adjust a Kaplain-Meier analysis to do so, or should I be using another model instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question raises an interesting point in survival analysis: How do we deal with different endpoints, such as graduation and dropping out in the context of university students.

The event of interest (in your example, dropping out) is what defines 'failure' in your survival analysis model. Other outcomes, such as graduation, are considered filtering since they prevent the observation of the event of interest. However, treating graduation as a simple right censoring (as opposed to students remained in the programme at the conclusion of the study) will not adequately reflect the reality that these students successfully navigated the risk period for the event of interest (dropping out).

> Should I be accounting for this in my analysis?

Yes, you must account for the many outcomes in your analysis. Graduation is a different type of endpoint than dropping out, and your research should reflect this.

> If so, I was thinking of just setting graduates to remain infinitely at Uni after they graduate, to substitute the fact they never dropped out. Would this be appropriate?

Unfortunately not.

Treating graduates as if they will remain at the university indefinitely is not correct. This strategy may cause the survival curves to be distorted because it indicates that graduates are still at risk of dropping out, which is not the case.

> If the previous solution is not appropriate, is there another way I could adjust a Kaplain-Meier analysis to do so, or should I be using another model instead?

Kaplan-Meier curves work best in settings with only one type of failure event. With various 'ending' occurrences (graduating, dropping out, still enrolled) in your scenario, a competing risks framework may be more applicable. Each sort of ending event is considered independently in a competing risks scenario. For example, one survival curve would be for dropping out and another for graduation.

Alternatively, you might perform separate Kaplan-Meier analyses for each subgroup based on the outcome (for example, one for those who dropped out and another for those who graduated).

And finally, you might use a Cox Proportional Hazards model or a Fine and Grey model with competing hazards. In some cases, these models can handle competing hazards more elegantly than the Kaplan-Meier technique.

To summarise, it is important to account for the many types of outcomes in your research. Rather than treating graduates as if they will remain at university indefinitely, explore approaches that more correctly reflect the nature of your data, such as competing risks analysis. This will provide a more detailed and accurate picture of university dropout rates over time.

Comment: Great, thanks Robert! This makes sense. I'll check out the competing risks/hazards framework.